# python3 pwntools can't set env for process or gdb

Tags: gdb, pwntools

I'm trying to debug some linux system binaries with pwntools and gdb, but I seem to be unable to set my desired environment variables for the process:

```
from pwn import *
elf = ELF("/usr/bin/su")
gs = 'show environment'
dbg = gdb.debug([elf.path], gdbscript=gs, env={"Z": "AAAA"})
dbg.interactive()
```

This code spawns the gdb-terminal for me, but during the show environment the desired `Z=AAAA` does not show up. It seems like the env-argument does not do anything, so maybe my understanding of it might be flawed.

Update:
env worked as intended, but the env of gdb are different from the ones of the debugged process. therefore checking /proc//environ shows the right env vars

Comment: `show environment` shows the environment which is used by gdb when it starts a new process. But as far as I can tell, pwntools uses gdbserver to start the target process, and only there `env` is used.

Comment: ok, makes sense. But then how do i get my env vars to be passed on to the elf?

Comment: Can you not check `/proc/PID/environ`?

Comment: ah yes, that helped me a lot. seems i was confusing gdb's environment with the programs env. Did not know that they are different, and it showed, that the env arg worked as intendet